# Python - How to share large dataset among multiple processes?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I need to read a large dataset (about 25GB of images) into memory and read it from multiple processes. None of the processes has to write, only read. All the processes are started using Python's multiprocessing module, so they have the same parent process. They train different models on the data and run independently of each other. The reason why I want to read it only one  time rather than in each process is that the memory on the machine is limited.

I have tried using Redis, but unfortunately it is extremely slow when many processes read from it. Is there another option to do this?

Is it maybe somehow possible to have another process that only serves as a "get the image with ID x" function? What Python module would be suited for this? Otherwise, I was thinking about implementign a small webserver using werkzeug or Flask, but I am not sure if that would become my new bottleneck then...

Another possibility that came to my mind was to use threads instead of processes, but since Python is not really doing "real" multithreading, this would probably become my new bottleneck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are on **linux** and the content is **read-only**, you can use the linux **fork** inheriting mechanism.

from [mp documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#all-start-methods):

> Better to inherit than pickle/unpickle
>
> When using the spawn or forkserver start methods many types from
>   multiprocessing need to be picklable so that child processes can use
>   them. However, one should generally avoid sending shared objects to
>   other processes using pipes or queues. Instead you should arrange the
>   program so that a process which needs access to a shared resource
>   created elsewhere can inherit it from an ancestor process.

which means:

Before you fork your child processes, prepare your big data in a **module level** variable (global to all the functions).

Then in the same module, run your child with multiprocessing in 'fork' mode `set_start_method('fork')`.

using this the sub-processes will see this variable without copying it. This happens due to linux forking mechanism that creates child processes with the same memory mapping as the parent (see "copy on write").

Comment: Awesome! Thank you. That was easier than expected :-) And is really fast now. Turns out that the default start method (at least on my machine) already is "fork". I am running linux.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest [`mmap`ping the files](https://docs.python.org/3/library/mmap.html), that way they can be shared across multiple processes as well as getting swapped in/out as appropriate

the details of this would depend on what you mean by "25GB of images" and how these models want to access the images

the basic idea would be to preprocess the images into an appropriate format (e.g. one big 4D `uint8` numpy array or maybe smaller ones, indicies could be `(image, row, column, channel)`) and save them in a format where they can be efficiently used by the models.  see [`numpy.memmap`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html) for some examples of this

I'd suggest preprocessing files into a useful format "offline", i.e. not part of the model training but a seperate program that is run first.  as this would probably take a while and you'd probably not want to do it every time

Comment: I will have a look into this. My 25GB of images are png images read by cv2, so essentially just 25GB of numpy arrays. I have already preprocessed them and stored it into npy files (one for each image).

Comment: Okay, so you suggest to have one array containing all images. I can do that, but in order for this to work, I would have to pad the images as they all have different resolutions. Would you still recommend this? I have some images in the 500x500 range and some in the 400x400 range. Rescaling all to the same size is not possible because it will have an impact on my model accuracy.